# Is it possible to set the IIS SMTP Advanced Logging tab via PowerShell?

Tags: logging, smtp, sendgrid

In Windows Server 2016/2019 using the IIS SMTP feature for creating an SMTP Relay I need to enable SMTP Logging and enable all the detailed options inside the Logging Properties (Advanced Tab) via PowerShell. See the hyperlink. [Image of advanced logging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrbIG.png)

I have the code to configure IIS SMTP to utilize SendGrid and enable the logging, but do not know how to configure the logging properties of the advanced logging tab to be enabled. Does anyone know how to do this or if it is possible?

```
function ConfigureSMTP
    {
    $SmtpConfig = Get-WMIObject -Namespace root/MicrosoftIISv2 -ComputerName localhost -Query "Select * From IisSmtpServerSetting"
    #$RelayIpList = @( 24, 0, 0, 128, 32, 0, 0, 128, 60, 0, 0, 128, 68, 0, 0, 128, 1, 0, 0, 0, 76, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 76, 0, 0, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 127, 0, 0, 1 )
    #$SmtpConfig.RelayIPList = $RelayIPList
    $SmtpConfig.AuthFlags = "1"
    $SmtpConfig.AuthBasic = $false
    $SmtpConfig.RouteAction = "268"
    $SmtpConfig.RouteUserName = "apikey"
    $SmtpConfig.RoutePassword = $apikeypass
    Write-Verbose "Sendgrid API Key: $apikeypass"
    $SmtpConfig.AlwaysUseSsl = $true
    $SmtpConfig.SmartHostType = "2"
    $SmtpConfig.DefaultDomain = $smtpfqdn
    $SmtpConfig.SmartHost = "smtp.sendgrid.net"
    $SmtpConfig.RemoteSmtpPort = "587"
    $smtpconfig.RelayIPList = @(24,0,0,128,32,0,0,128,60,0,0,128,68,0,0,128,1,0,0,0,76,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,76,0,0,128,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255)
    $SmtpConfig.Put() 
    Set-Service "SMTPSVC" -StartupType Automatic -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Start-Service "SMTPSVC" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    # This flips 1=logging on, 2=logging off
     $mySite = [ADSI]"IIS://Localhost/smtpsvc/1"
     $mySite.Put("LogType", 1)
     $mySite.SetInfo()
    #

}
```

Comment: Hey did you manage to figure this out? I am looking as well. Thanks!

Comment: yes I just did now...not sure why I didn't think of this before but I didn't write the original script.  if you look at the results of $SMTPConfig it will show all the properties it knows how to set $SmtpConfig = Get-WMIObject -Namespace root/MicrosoftIISv2 -ComputerName localhost -Query "Select * From IisSmtpServerSetting" So I just copied the entire section like below (thread made me cut it off but you will see an example below) $SmtpConfig.LogExtFileBytesRecv="True"
 $SmtpConfig.LogExtFileBytesSent="True"
 $SmtpConfig.LogExtFileClientIp="True"

Comment: If this helped you out please see the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The key to solving this was to look at all the properties that were returned with $SMTPConfig. This showed all the extended logging properties to set to True.
$SmtpConfig = Get-WMIObject -Namespace root/MicrosoftIISv2 -ComputerName localhost -Query "Select * From IisSmtpServerSetting"

```
function ConfigureSMTP
    {
    $SmtpConfig = Get-WMIObject -Namespace root/MicrosoftIISv2 -ComputerName localhost -Query "Select * From IisSmtpServerSetting"
    #$RelayIpList = @( 24, 0, 0, 128, 32, 0, 0, 128, 60, 0, 0, 128, 68, 0, 0, 128, 1, 0, 0, 0, 76, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 76, 0, 0, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 127, 0, 0, 1 )
    #$SmtpConfig.RelayIPList = $RelayIPList
    $SmtpConfig.AuthFlags = "1"
    $SmtpConfig.AuthBasic = $false
    $SmtpConfig.RouteAction = "268"
    $SmtpConfig.RouteUserName = "apikey"
    $SmtpConfig.RoutePassword = $apikeypass
    Write-Verbose "Sendgrid API Key: $apikeypass"
    $SmtpConfig.AlwaysUseSsl = $true
    $SmtpConfig.SmartHostType = "2"
    $SmtpConfig.DefaultDomain = $smtpfqdn
    $SmtpConfig.SmartHost = "smtp.sendgrid.net"
    $SmtpConfig.RemoteSmtpPort = "587"
    $smtpconfig.RelayIPList = @(24,0,0,128,32,0,0,128,60,0,0,128,68,0,0,128,1,0,0,0,76,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,76,0,0,128,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,255)
    $SmtpConfig.MaxMessageSize =16777216
    $SmtpConfig.MaxSessionSize=16777216
    $SmtpConfig.LogExtFileBytesRecv="True"
    $SmtpConfig.LogExtFileBytesSent="True"
    $SmtpConfig.LogExtFileClientIp="True"
    $SmtpConfig.LogExtFileComputerName="True"
    $SmtpConfig.LogExtFileCookie="True"
    $SmtpConfig.LogExtFileDate="True"
    $SmtpConfig.LogExtFileHost="True"
    $SmtpConfig.LogExtFileHttpStatus="True"
    $SmtpConfig.LogExtFileHttpSubStatus="True"
    $SmtpConfig.LogExtFileMethod="True"
    $SmtpConfig.LogExtFileProtocolVersion="True"
    $SmtpConfig.LogExtFileReferer="True"
    $SmtpConfig.LogExtFileServerIp="True"
    $SmtpConfig.LogExtFileServerPort="True"
    $SmtpConfig.LogExtFileSiteName="True"
    $SmtpConfig.LogExtFileTime="True"
    $SmtpConfig.LogExtFileTimeTaken="True"
    $SmtpConfig.LogExtFileUriQuery="True"
    $SmtpConfig.LogExtFileUriStem="True"
    $SmtpConfig.LogExtFileUserAgent="True"
    $SmtpConfig.LogExtFileUserName="True"
    $SmtpConfig.LogExtFileWin32Status="True"
    $SmtpConfig.Put() 
    Set-Service "SMTPSVC" -StartupType Automatic -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Start-Service "SMTPSVC" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    # This flips 1=logging on, 2=logging off
     $mySite = [ADSI]"IIS://Localhost/smtpsvc/1"
     $mySite.Put("LogType", 1)
     $mySite.SetInfo()
    }
```